# Control indentation with Org–Babel

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode, literate-programming, org-babel

When writing literate Python with [Org–Babel](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/), I need to be able to control the indentation level (either explicitly with `:indentation-level 3` or implicitly with some clever indication).

Here's an example file that demonstrates the problem.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle "sample.py"
  class Test:
      def __init__(self):
          self.a = 'a test class'
#+END_SRC
#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle "sample.py"
      def say_hi(self):
          print 'Hi from this Test object!'
          print 'ID: {}'.format(repr(self))
          print 'Data: {}'.format(str(self.__dict__))
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Hm, org-babel respects the indentation of the programming mode. If you edit the code snippet with `C-'` you can change the indentation with `C-c >` from `python-mode`. But, I guess this is not what you want. What is the reason for the wanted option `:indentation-level`?

Comment: @Tobias When I `org-babel-tangle` the file, indentation is not respected given a whitespace prefix with the `#+begin_src` environment.  Everything is alright if I keep it all in one source block, but good sense says to split it up and explain each part.

Comment: But, this works for me! All indentation is copied verbatim from the org file.

Comment: @Tobias How strange… I will upload a video to prove I'm not crazy XD

Comment: @Tobias Org version 8.2.4: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0gGW3T4zRo (warning: my keyboard is a little loud)

Comment: Sorry that you had to go through this. After your video I re-started `emacs` with `-q` and recognized what you mean. The solution is in the answer.

Comment: @Tobias I just updated emacs for a new machine so I'll re-test your answer.  Just as a record for what I did in the meantime, using noweb references solves the issue in practice.

Answer (score 9):

Set `org-src-preserve-indentation` to `t`.

Comment: It seems that, even with this set, the first line is still indented poorly: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0EwwH.png

Comment: Well, this does work, but an annoying side-effect is that all the code blocks (not only python) become left justified. Is there a way to avoid this, or at least to restrict this option only to python source blocks? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't perfectly like [Tobias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20903001/9347694) because when I `org-edit-special` (`C-c '`) a code block, my python-mode buffer would yell at me (I have several python minor modes with syntax checkers) because of the unexpected indent for blocks with stand-alone methods (because with `org-src-preserve-indentation` set, I would have indents in front of all my methods in their individual blocks). So instead, I like this solution using org-mode's [:noweb](https://orgmode.org/manual/noweb.html#noweb) header argument:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle "sample.py" :noweb yes
  class Test:
      <<init_method>> # these are indented
      <<more_methods>> # these are indented
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC python :noweb-ref init_method
  def __init__(self):
      self.a = 'a test class'
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC python :noweb-ref more_methods
  def say_hi(self):
      print 'Hi from this Test object!'
      print 'ID: {}'.format(repr(self))
      print 'Data: {}'.format(str(self.__dict__))
#+END_SRC
```

As long as you just indent the Noweb syntax references (the double `<< >>`) in your class definition, the other blocks ("init_method" and "more_methods") will be tangled with respect to your indentation. So, the final output "sample.py" file looks like this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a test class'
    def say_hi(self):
        print 'Hi from this Test object!'
        print 'ID: {}'.format(repr(self))
        print 'Data: {}'.format(str(self.__dict__))
```

Nice!

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not the desired solution but as a work around you can insert a comment (specific to your programming language) in the source block and make the desired indentation after that comment.  This will also preserve the indentation when exiting the `edit-buffer`

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle "sample.py"
  class Test:
      def __init__(self):
          self.a = 'a test class'
#+END_SRC
#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle "sample.py"
  # This is my dummy python comment to keep the correct indentation 
      def say_hi(self):
          print 'Hi from this Test object!'
          print 'ID: {}'.format(repr(self))
          print 'Data: {}'.format(str(self.__dict__))
#+END_SRC
```